# Is the union of l^p a Banach space under some norm?

Tags: banach-spaces, norms

As a set of sequences, take the union of $\ell^p$, $p\geq 1$. As $p$ increases, the $\ell ^p$ space is larger, with strict inclusion.

However, this infinite union is strictly contained in $c_0$, consider
$x_n = 1/\log (n+1)$, so the usual $c_0$ norm will not yield a closed space, as $c_{00}$ is dense within any $\ell ^p$.

Is there some norm which turns the union of l^p into a Banach space, presumably with $c_{00} $dense?

Comment: This probably isn’t the kind of answer you were hoping for. As a vector space, it has a basis of the same cardinality as the cardinality of a basis for $l^2$. You can therefore “copy” the l^2 norm onto your space.

Comment: Are you talking about a Hamel basis? In which case one needs AC and necessarily can't write it down explicitly. Or a Schauder basis, where we can't be certain one exists until we actually have a norm? And what do you mean by "copy"? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hamel basis. There is a vector space isomorphism $\phi:X\to l^2$ between the two spaces. Then you can define a norm on $X$ by $|x|=\|\phi(x)\|$. Of course this is not explicit as you say, and depends on the axiom of choice.

Comment: As pointed out above, the question of whether a given vector space has a Banach space structure is one about cardinality.  However, your space, as a union of a sequence of Banach spaces, has a natural and  perfectly respectable locally convex structure (the inductive limit) for which the finite sequences are dense.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: it's not explicitly stated in the question, but I suspect the OP wants the canonical embeddings of the $\ell^p$-spaces into the union to be continuous.

Comment: So, I agree that the cardinality of the 2 Hamel bases would be the same. However I am not convinced that the union would be complete under the norm derived from this. Further, I would like to know if one could actually write a norm down, which almost definitionally would require not using AC...

Comment: If two vector spaces are isomorphic (which they are if they have Hamel bases of the same cardinality), and one is a Banach space, then you can transfer the norm to the other and this normed space is isometrically isomorphic to the first  one and so also Banach. In the other direction if you could put a norm on your space to make it a Banach space in such a way that the coordinate functionals are continuous, then by a suitable version of the closed graph theorem its topology would have to agree with the one I described above and this is clearly not the case.

Comment: By the way, to look at your question from the positive side, namely that of searching for a well behaved functional analytic point of view, then the lc topology I described is one of a type investigated by Komatsu and has many useful properties. For example, it is a complete, Hausdorff, bornological $(DF)$-space, its dual is naturally identifiable with the (Fréchet space) intersection of the $\ell^p$-spaces and there are nice descriptions of its bounded sets and weakly convergent sequences.

Comment: Maybe take the dual of some modular sequence space $\ell\{M_n\}$ with $M_n$ chosen wisely.  For instance if $M_n(t)=t^{1+\delta_n}$ with $\delta_n\downarrow 0$, then the uniform $\Delta_2$ condition is satisfied. I'm worried it will just turn out to be $\ell_1$, but maybe not.

Comment: Many thanks, I think the modular space suggestion is a good place to look! Will try

Answer (score 2):

Although such a norms exists by the axiom of choice, it is an interesting question what nice properties the unit vector basis $(e_n)_n$ could possibly have. From my point of view, it cannot have very nice ones.

For example, $(e_n)_n$ cannot be a Schauder basis. It cannot even be the spatial component of a Markushevich basis. Let's see why not.

Let $X = \cup_{1\leq p<\infty}\ell_p$, $\|\cdot\|_X$ be a complete norm for $X$, and let us assume that $(e_n,f_n)_n$ is an M-basis for $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$.

For every $1\leq p < \infty$ the inclusion map $I_p:\ell_p\to X$ is well defined. By the closed graph theorem it is also bounded. Indeed, if $(x_n)_n$ converges to zero in $\ell_p$ and $(x_n)_n$ converges to some $x\in X$ (with respect to $\|\cdot\|_X$) then $x$ must be zero. Here we used the fact that $(e_n)_n$ is the spatial component of an $M$-basis and completeness. Both will be used again later.

But it is also the case that for no $1\leq p<\infty$, $\ell_p$ the map $I_p$ is an isomorphism, otherwise your space $X$ would be just $\ell_p$. A small argument (using automatic continuity of linear maps on finite dimensional spaces) tells us that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if we restrict $I_p$ to the tail-space $Y_n$ of $\ell_p$ (i.e., the subspace of all vectors in $\ell_p$ with the first $n$ coordinates zero), then it cannot be an isomorphism. The conclusion is that for any $1\leq p<\infty$, $\varepsilon >0$, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exist $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and a scalar sequence $(a_i)_{i=n+1}^{n+k}$ so that if we define $x = \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k}a_ie_i$ then $\|x\|_p = 1$ while $\|x\|_X\leq \varepsilon$.

Now we are almost finished. Take $p_n = n$ and inductively pick $(a_i)_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_n}$ so that if $x_n = \sum_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_n}a_ie_i$, then $\|x_n\|_{p_n} = 1$, yet $\|x_n\|_X\leq 2^{-n}$.

We use completeness again and put $x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$. For every $i\in\mathbb{N}$, the $i$'th coordinate of $x$ (i.e., $f_i(x)$) is $a_i$. By assumption, there must exist some $1\leq p<\infty$ so that $(a_i)_i\in\ell_p$. This is absurd because for every $1\leq p<\infty$, if we pick $n$ with $p_n\geq p$ then

$$\|(a_i)_i\|_p \geq \|(a_i)\|_{p_n} \geq \|(a_i)_{i\geq k_{n-1}+1}\|_{p_n} = (\sum_{j=n}^\infty \|x_j\|_{p_n}^{p_n})^{1/p_n} \geq (\sum_{j=n}^\infty \|x_j\|_{p_j}^{p_n})^{1/p_n} = \infty.$$